# ¿Cómo cargo una posición o valor por defecto en un Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

Estoy tratando de actualizar mis datos, pero lo que no puedo realizar es cargar el valor en el item del spinner:

por ejemplo en mi spinner cargo nombre de países (Seleccionar un país, Perú, Ecuador, Colombia, ...), supongamos que el registro que deseo modificar tiene como valor seleccionado **Perú**, pero al momento de cargar este registro en un fragment no carga el spinner en el item que debe ser **Perú**, si no que carga en el principio.

> Aquí les dejo el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
//SQLiteOpenHelper
 DataBaseManagerRecordatorios mManager;
//[Spinner]
Spinner mSpinnerLista;
//Variables para el combo
ArrayList<String> comboLista;
ArrayAdapter<String> comboAdapter;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actualizar_recordatorio, container, false);

//Spinner
mSpinnerLista = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

poblarSpinner();

mSpinnerLista.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

return v;

}

public void poblarSpinner(){

    comboLista = new ArrayList<>();

    int sizeLista = mManager.getListaSpinner().size();

    comboLista.add("Seleccione un país");

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeLista; i++){
        comboLista.add(mManagerR.getListaSpinner().get(i).getPaises());
    }

    comboAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.spinner_item, comboLista);

    comboAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

    mSpinnerLista.setAdapter(comboAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    int idItemSelected = parent.getId();
    switch (idItemSelected){
        case R.id.spinner:

            if(position != 0) { hago esta condición por que agrego un item desde código
                //lógica para que seleccione funciona
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

> A todo esto quiero saber como devolver una posición en el adaptador del spinner, cuando se desea modificar el registro, para poder cargar el país que que tiene agregado el registro y no el primer ítem.

Comment: Bueno amigos ya lo logre con el siguiente código `mSpinnerLista.setSelection(numeroEnteroDeLaPosicion)`, espero les sirva.

Comment: También encontré un articulo que quizá los interese [click](https://carmazone.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/inicializacion-personalizada-de-spinner/)

Comment: Si lo has solucionado, escribe una respuesta y márcalla como correcta, así el resto de usuarios verán la solución rápidamente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo [`spinner#setSelection(int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int,%20boolean)) donde le especificas cual elemento deseas seleccionar por codigo:

```
//...
mSpinnerLista.setAdapter(comboAdapter);
mSpinnerLista.setSelection(indiceValorAseleccionar);
```